# yii1: Разлогинивает на поддоменах через 20мин

Tags: php, yii, авторизация, поддомены

Использую Yii 1. В конфиге сайта domen.ua прописываю:

```
'session' => array(
    'cookieParams' => array(
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'domain' => '.domen.ua'
        )
),
'user' => array(
    'loginUrl' => array('auth/auth'),
            'class' => WebUser',
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => array('domain' => '.domen.ua'),
),
```

В конфиге сайта my.domen.ua прописываю:

```
'session' => array(
    'cookieParams' => array(
        'domain' =>  '.domen.ua',
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ),
),
'user' => array(
    'loginUrl' => array('auth/auth'),
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => array('domain' =>  '.domen.ua'),
),
```

При авторизации ставлю `$duration = 31536000`. Все замечательно авторизирует и с основного домена, и с поддомена.

НО! На основном домене кука хранится столько сколько она задана - 31536000 (около года). При переходе с сайта domen.ua на my.domen.ua пользователь авторизирован. Но если долгое время (примерно мин 20 ) не заходить на сайт domen.ua, а потом в адресной строке ввести my.domen.ua - пользователь окажется гостем. МАГИЯ! А если зайти на domen.ua - снова Авторизирован! 
Вопрос , почему разлогинивает на поддомене через определенное время? В devtools как бы сессия есть... Логиню юзера

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
```

где `$duration = 31536000`

Давно бьюсь с этой проблемой... Решение форумов, к сожалению, не помогло еще ни одно...

Answer (score 1):

У вас переопределённый класс CWebUser, может стоит заглянуть туда?

А вообще посмотрите в сторону параметра CWebUser::**authTimeout** и CWebUser::**absoluteAuthTimeout**.

Можете установить им значение в конфиге компонента user

Если установлена опция allowAutoLogin, то авторизация основана на cookie.